# Используете ли Вы в разработке android приложении lambda?

Tags: java, android, lambda

Используете ли Вы в разработке android приложении lambda? если да, какие подводные камни есть? и стоит их использовать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Используем.
2. Подводных камней нет. Можно воспринимать их как синтаксический сахар.
3. Стоит. Сильно сокращает и облегчает чтение кода.

Пример вешания слушателя нажатий на Вьюху, по которому должен быть вызван один метод:

Без лямбд

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         method();
    }
}
```

С лямбдами:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(view -> method());
```

Или так, если метод в этом же классе определён и на вход принимает тот параметр, который поступает в лямбду:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(this::method);
```

Итого -5 строк кода и минус много символов только для этого конкретного случая. А их тысячи. Особенно если какой-нибудь RxJava взять

Comment: Я бы добавил что метод в классе должен на вход принимать тот параметр, который поступает в лямбду, для использования вызова без явной передачи переменной (this::method)

Comment: @zTrap, дополнил ответ)